# "poetry update" takes 3 hours on a tiny project - what am I doing wrong?

Tags: python, python-poetry

I have a tiny Python (3.10) project (named crawler) that imports SDKs from Azure (azure-identity, azure-core) and AWS (boto3).

Then I have a different one-file project (named crawler-tester) that imports the first one as a module.

I'm using poetry and the pyproject.toml file looks like this:

```ini
[tool.poetry]
name = "crawler-tester"
version = "0.1.0"
description = ""
authors = ["Your Name <you@example.com>"]
packages = [
    { include = "../crawler/" },
]

[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "^3.10"
finops-crawler = {path = "../crawler"}

[tool.poetry.dev-dependencies]
python-dotenv = "^1.0.0"

[build-system]
requires = ["poetry-core>=1.0.0"]
build-backend = "poetry.core.masonry.api"
```

From what I've understood then this is the "development mode" where it should work in a way that if I edit my module then it would be picked up immediately.

Except the result is as follows:

```
(.venv) stuff:/mnt/c/Users/myname/github/crawler-tester$ poetry update
Updating dependencies
Resolving dependencies... (11184.5s)

Writing lock file

Package operations: 5 installs, 2 updates, 0 removals

  • Updating urllib3 (2.0.3 -> 1.26.16)
  • Installing jmespath (1.0.1)
  • Installing python-dateutil (2.8.2)
  • Installing botocore (1.29.156)
  • Installing s3transfer (0.6.1)
  • Installing boto3 (1.26.156)
  • Updating finops-crawler (0.1.2 -> 0.1.3 /mnt/c/Users/myname/github/finops-crawler)
```

Notice the almost 3 hours it took to resolve dependencies.

I'm obviously doing something wrong here, but I can't figure out what.
The changes are also not picked up automatically - I have to increase the version number and do `poetry update` for it to happen.

Answer (score 0):

There is a known issue with boto3's compatibility with `urllib3^2`, try giving poetry a hint that your project requires version 1 of `urllib3`.

```ini
[tool.poetry.group.dev.dependencies]
urllib3 = "<2"
```

https://github.com/orgs/python-poetry/discussions/7937